# Is wearing Langot necessary to do Push ups at home?

Tags: exercise, workout-routines, push-ups

I have been doing home workout routine of 100 Decline push ups and 50 diamond push ups. I have been wearing a Langot (loin Cloth) to cover my testicles from any harm since I stared working out 10 years ago. So my question is do I need to wear the Langot even for my home push up work out? I want to stop wearing it. Will it harm my testicles if I do push ups without a Langot at home?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. How would pushups ever harm your testicles?

Comment: When I first joined the gym I was suggested by other people in the gym to wear a Langot. Ever since I have been practicing that. Now I want to stop wearing it. So i wanted a advice.

Comment: Most men on Earth have never worn a "langot" in their life and most of them have done push ups in the past and their testicles haven't exploded or whatever. Sometimes basic logic is your friend

Comment: It may be worth noting that these garments are traditionally worn during wrestling to prevent hydrocele and hernia.

Answer (score 7):

Getting one's testicles in the way during pushups sounds like a problem that is exclusive to those who are particularly blessed with tremendous balls. Or cursed with extremely sensitive ones.

No, there is generally no problem with *not* wearing a loin cloth during pushups. In fact, I've never even heard of a single person needing to do so.

But the test is very simple. If your testicles hurt during pushups without a langot, but not while you're wearing one; put it back on.

Answer (score 2):

As per Alec's answer, it is unlike that you need this particular form of loincloth. In its traditional format, it is meant to prevent a hernia, or [hydrocele](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/hydrocele/symptoms-causes/syc-20363969), i.e. fluid build-up in the testicles. Push-ups are highly unlikely to introduce this level of strain. You may wish to wear more protective garments such as a traditional loincloth or a weightlifting belt if you move on to lifting more than mere bodyweight.